# Why loss metrics in tensorflow 2.x become NaN, but good in tensorflow 1.x-gpu

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model, it uses the "get_updates" method to optimize the parameters, and it runs well in TensorFlow 1.15. But in TensorFlow 2.x it can not run anymore, so I added

> "import TensorFlow.compat.v1 as tf tf.disable_v2_behavior() "

at the beginning of the code to try to make it good, it could run, but all loss metrics became NaN. How can I fix it?
My operating system is Windows 10, the video card is Geforce RTX 3060, it seems can not use TensorFlow 1.X.

Comment: It is bit difficult to replicate your issue with out code. Can you please share standalone code replicate the same? so that we can try to help you.Thanks!